I have a Category model and a subCategory model and a product model which has foreign key with category and sub category
I have a Category model and a subCategory model and a product model which has foreign key with category and sub category .  Whenever a client will add a product then he will select a category and according to that the related subcategory should shown or change without submitting the form in django admin panel.
Please tell me how to do this. The value should change on "onChange event" of the category.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

To dynamically update the subcategory dropdown in Django admin panel based on the selected category you can implement JavaScript to capture the onChange event of the category dropdown, triggering an AJAX request to a Django view.
You can also preload all subcategory options for each category and then use JavaScript to filter and display them based on the selected category
but less efficient if you have a lot of categories.
Then Django view will look for related subcategories based on the selected category and will return JSON data. JavaScript updates the subcategory dropdown options with returned JSON data.
